# insert browser's history entry before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two web pages: index.php and handler.php
index.php has a form, that submits to handler.php like this:

> handler.php?input=some+data

My goal is to do something so that browser's back button takes me to `index.php?input=some+data` instead of simply `index.php`. How can I do that? Ideally, I'd prefer to do as much as possible using php instead of js

**Solution:**
I added submit handler that does this:

```
function onFormUpdate()
{
    window.history.replaceState({} , '', 'index.php?' + document.forms[0].serialize());
}
```

this way, form will be submitted not from `index.php`, but from `index.php?input=some+data`. That is, back button will bring me back to `index.php?input=some+data`.

Comment: I don't think that modifying the history is possible. You may consider using the hash (#) of the url before submitting your form (for example).

Comment: Wait, do you want to have the data sent to `index.php` when going back to the page where you sent that data?

Comment: @Max yes, that's exactly what I want it to do. The same data should be sent to index.php when try to come back to index.php. Nicolas: I don't need to modify history, I need to *make* that history. For example, I could submit form to index.php and then somehow redirect to handler.php with the same URL params. This way, back button would take me back to `index.php?input=some+data`... the problem here is that when I actually go to index.php?input=some+data it will redirect me to handler.php?input=some+data

Comment: Having found this question rather interesting, I put some research into it (unfortunately without success, which is why I'm posting a comment instead...). The only method I can come up with is by using sessions/cookies, and having experimented with that, I can tell you that it's more complicated than it sounds... Even if everything may seem as it should work, the page in-between the HTTP-response-headers `Location` won't get saved into history (which is what you want), and sadly, it doesn't seem to be a very accurate method.

Comment: @Max suggestion by parchment works perfectly. I updated the question with the solution

Comment: @Pavel Oh, well that's probably a better method. Good to hear that there's a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by: (JS)

```
history.replaceState({}, '', 'index.php?input=some+data');
```

Before submitting.

But I don't think you need to do this, my browser (firefox, though I think chrome would do the same) saves form data before submitting, so when I go back from the handler, the form still have the input.

Comment: I'll try that. In FF I used to get form preserved, then at some point after I updated FF it stopped working and form data gets reset now. Chrome preserves it... but the goal is actually to get that index.php?input=some+data in the real history so that I could go back and copy-pase that link. SO it's not only about preserving form data.

Comment: Verified, it does exactly what I want. `onsubmit="history.replaceState({}, '', 'index.php?'+document.forms[0].serialize());"`